# Can't install a github repository

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/icoprimers/pyttrex) repository from Github, in order to work on it. I downloaded the files but i keep getting the error 'no module named pyttrex' (pyttrex is the name of the repository).

I tried to install it using pip (`pip install pyttrex`) but pip didn't even find the module, after that i tried with `pip install git+https://github.com/icoprimers/pyttrex`, but i got the error `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1`, although setuptools is upgraded. I have two versions of python installed: 2.7 and 3.6, i just can't see the error.

Comment: pyttrex must be the package that you have downloaded. Add it to pythonpath.

Comment: Is there a way to add it with two versions of python installed?

Comment: Add it to both Python versions? No. Add it to each version one by one? Yes. You probably have a tool called `pip2` or `pip3` installed.

Comment: So i should do using pip3 install pyttrex? The problem is that when i do that i get 'could not find a a version that satisfies the requirements for pyttrex'

Comment: Are you trying to run the scripts or import them to be used in another script?

Comment: I'm using the scripts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `pip install pyttrex` installs packages from PyPI. There is no `pyttrex` at PyPI — URL https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttrex returns error 404 — hence `pip` cannot install it.

At Github repository there is no `setup.py`. Resume — the repo is not a package and isn't pip-installable. Your best bet is to clone the repository and copy subdirectory `pyttrex` manually to `site-packages`.

Comment: So i found site-packages, and i copied pyttrex there, however when i run one of the scripts in the folder i got the same error

Comment: To debug that you should show us the version of Python, the path to `site-packages` and what you copied there (is there `pyttrex/__init__.py` in path to `site-packages`?) Verify that `pyttrex` is importable in Python.

Comment: Ok, i made a stupid error, i imported the folder on site-packages but i did not see that the name was pyttrex-master and not pyttrex. So i renamed the pyttrex-master folder 'pyttrex' and i'm not getting the error 'no module named pyttrex'. The error i'm getting right now is 'cannot import name market_candles' but i should be able to solve it